# Is it possible to use 'like' condition in gt/lt while reading from HBase

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I have HBase table rowkey build on `StartDate`, `EndDate` : `2014010120140201` 
I use pig for reading the table.
 I know I can use gt/lt condidtions while reading from HBase, but I was wondering if it's possible to use 'like' condition with pattern matching character, for example `201401012014`% instead of `- gt  2014010120140000`

Regards
Pawel

Comment: Why wouldn't you just type the extra four zeroes? Also, do you really mean that you would use the `%` wildcard in an argument to `-gt`? I don't understand what a wildcard in a comparison could mean.

Comment: OK, the two dates were just an example. The row key is actualy more complicated. It consists of StartDate, EndDate, SourceIP, SourcePort, DestinationIP, DestinationPort. While quering I'm able to provide only StartDate and SourceIP. It just would be easier to use wildcard instead of playing with zeros. What's worse, SourcePort and DestinationPort may have length from 2 to 4 characters. Probably pattern for rowkey should to be changed but I'm wonderings if I can use the existing one as it is...

Answer (score 0):

An Example of pattern matching:

```
res = Filter Data By X matches '.*blabla.*';
```

Comment: This is true, but I'm asking if it's possible in gte and lte condition in code like this: `records = LOAD 'hbase://table_name' using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage
('fam:*','-loadKey=true -gte=052014030207 -lt=052014030208')`

Comment: Well I don't know about the HBaseStorage sorry. 
But if you want to extract pathern from your keys you have the REGEX_EXTRACT which could be used in a {} block of a foreach in order to do some pre-processing : 
      http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/func.html#regex-extract 
I hope this could help, good luck :)